# Hidden form field with decimal value shows as empty in $_POST

Tags: php

I have a form field that looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="last_amount_paid" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">
```

`$amount` is set to `100.00` and shows up fine if I change the form field from `hidden` to `text`.

`$_POST['last_amount_paid ']` is empty when I try and retrieve the value after submit.

I ran `var_dump($_POST);` and it's showing up as a string and empty

```
["last_amount_paid"]=> string(0) ""
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

John

** Fixed this by converting to a string before sending the form:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="last_amount_paid" value="<?php echo (string)$amount; ?>">
```

Comment: open generated html and check field value there. Check is you have js submit.

Comment: @u_mulder opened the html and the value is there - 100.00. I am using Stripe to take payments so the button is not a submit and it's running js and then reloads the page to run php.

Comment: Well it sounds like the JavaScript you haven't posted is incredibly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

** Fixed this by converting to a string before sending the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="last_amount_paid" value="<?php echo (string)$amount; ?>">
```